# Xorg and bitmap font (BDF/PCF) with full unicode support?

Tags: xorg, fontconfig

Recently I attempted to create a BDF font (using font-forge's full-unicode encoding `ISO10646`).

While the file was written correctly as far as I can tell. X11/freetype/font-config aren't using glyph's added: `U8658 (⇒) U8594 (→)`

Is there a way to support these characters?

---

Incase it helps, [here are the BDF font-files](https://github.com/ideasman42/triskweline-code-font/commit/cdce0b32f0e70d65b3819b5f22bd78c48167cdbe).

Comment: [GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html) (available as package on many distros) attempts to be a very complete unicode font, and also exists in PCF form (`xfonts-unifont` on Debian). So there should be a way to support these characters. Maybe look at the Unifont PCF files and see what they do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 problems causing this.

#### Encoding

The following encodings were set:

```
CHARSET_REGISTRY "ISO8859"
CHARSET_COLLECTIONS "ISOLatin1Encoding"
```

Which needed to be replaced by an encoding with unicode support:

```
CHARSET_REGISTRY "ISO10646"
```

*Note that `CHARSET_COLLECTIONS` isn
t needed*.

#### Character Names

FontForge was naming characters with with a descriptive title, `unifont` uses `U+HEX` format, which was needed so Xorg would load the font properly.

Eg:

```
STARTCHAR percent
ENCODING 37
```

Needed to be changed to:

```
STARTCHAR U+0025
ENCODING 37
```

I couldn't find a good way to do this in FontForge, so ended up loading font names from unifont and applying them to my own.